# Where does sourceCompatibility directive belong in build.gradle?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have a java project in Android studio, and I am trying to use the "sourceCompatibility" directive as follows:

```
// build.gradle

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

the IDE reports that the "sourceCompatibility" and "targetCompatibility" directives are not used. I can't find where they should be placed - where should it go in the build.gradle file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust the IDE for Gradle file inspection - it treats them as, how should I say, source code files. What matters is whether script works when parsed or executed by Gradle. So disregard IDE's warnings, you did put the directives correctly.